# AsyncTasks taking long time to complete

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask

I am calling for these classes to occur in the onCreate() method and they all have booleans at the bottom of their class which they will set to true once they complete.  Only then will my SurfaceView draw what it needs to.  Why are these three classes taking so long to complete?

enemy, cloud, & bullet    are all Bitmaps which I load before I call their class

```
public class handleBullets extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            Random r = new Random();
            Log.d(null, "Spawn E-Bulles");
            for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++)
            {
                Enemy tempE = enemies.get(i);
                if(System.currentTimeMillis() - tempE.lastBulletSpawn >= 800 && tempE.x <= SCREEN_WIDTH)
                {
                    EnemyBullet eb = new EnemyBullet(tempE.x, tempE.y, enemyBullet.getWidth(), enemyBullet.getHeight(), enemy.getWidth(), enemy.getHeight());
                    enemyBullets.add(eb);

                    tempE.lastBulletSpawn = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
            }
            Log.d(null, "Spawn Bullets");
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastPBSpawn >= 400)
            {
                Bullet b = new Bullet(x, y, player.getWidth(), player.getHeight());
                bullets.add(b);

                lastPBSpawn = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            Log.d(null, "Remove Bullets");
            for(int i = bullets.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) 
            {
                Bullet tempB = bullets.get(i);
                if(tempB.x >= SCREEN_WIDTH)
                    bullets.remove(i);
            }
            Log.d(null, "removeEnemy Bullets");
            for(int i = enemyBullets.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) 
            {
                EnemyBullet tempEB = enemyBullets.get(i);
                if(tempEB.x <= 0 - enemyBullet.getWidth())
                    enemyBullets.remove(i);
            }
            Log.d(null, "Explosion Renders");
            for(int i = explosions.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) 
            {
                Explosion tempEx = explosions.get(i);
                tempEx.update();
                if(tempEx.duration <= 0)
                    explosions.remove(i);
            }
            initial_bullets = true;
            return null;
        }
    }
    public class handleEnemy extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            Log.d(null, "Spawning Enemies...");
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastESpawn >= 750 && enemy != null)
            {
                Enemy x = new Enemy(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, enemy.getWidth(), enemy.getHeight());
                enemies.add(x);

                lastESpawn = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            Log.d(null, "Enemies Spawned");
            //
            Log.d(null, "Removing Enemies...");
            for(int i = enemies.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) 
            {
                Enemy tempE = enemies.get(i);
                if(tempE.x <= 0 - enemy.getWidth())
                    enemies.remove(tempE);
            }
            Log.d(null, "Enemies Removed");
            //
            initial_enemies = true;
            return null;
        }
    }
    public class handleClouds extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            Log.d(null, "Generating Clouds...");
            Random r = new Random();
            if(r.nextInt(200) == 0 && clouds.size() <= 6 && cloudBM1 != null && cloudBM2 != null)
            {
                Cloud c = new Cloud(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, cloudBM1.getWidth(), cloudBM2.getHeight());
                clouds.add(c);
            }
            Log.d(null, "Clouds Generated");
            //
            Log.d(null, "Removing Clouds...");
            for(int i = clouds.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) 
            {
                Cloud tempC = clouds.get(i);
                if(tempC.x <= 0 - cloudBM1.getWidth() && tempC.dir == 0)
                    clouds.remove(i);
                if(tempC.x >= SCREEN_WIDTH && tempC.dir == 1)
                    clouds.remove(i);
            }
            Log.d(null, "Clouds Removed");
            //
            initial_clouds = true;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. check Order of execution

Comment: Are the tasks actually taking a long time to complete, or is it that the activity (or SurfaceView) just isn't aware that they have finished?

Comment: Raghunandan - What do you mean?  Are you saying that I should not have it in doInBackground?

Ted Hopp - I have the SurfaceView checking a boolean as in if(initial_clouds &&...)

Comment: What does this do `Cloud c = new Cloud(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, cloudBM1.getWidth(), cloudBM2.getHeight());`? Does it access `UI` elements?

Comment: All the Xxx x = new Xxx() reference another class that is used to make enemies/clouds/bullets...

Comment: I suggest that you first verify that the problem is what you think it is. You can log the start and completion times of each `doInBackground` method and check whether they are, indeed, taking a long time. I suspect that the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Might be that your tasks are executed serial. Try executing your tasks in parallel using `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)` instead of calling `execute()`.